# How to set truststore file with System.setProperty in spring boot application? or by other feasible approach?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, keystore, truststore

I am setting truststore file in Appstarter class with System.setProperty, but while running the service(spring boot rest application), program terminates 'Process finished with exit code 1'. By commenting system.setProperty able to Run the service but getting 'sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed'.So what causes the service to terminate by setting truststore in appstarter? How to set truststore in this case for my application? I have already tried by reading jks file from classpathResource,input stream approach but nothing seems to work.

However I have tried the same approach(setting truststore with System.setProperty in appstarter) in other service , where I able to make a Rest call with rest template without certificate error 'sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed'

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.data.services")
public class AppStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer  implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppStarter .class);
    static {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "src/main/resources/truststore/truststore.jks");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication.run(AppStarter.class, args);
    }
     @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
      return new ModelMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }


    @Override
    public SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(AppStarter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running from a jar (or several)? A class or resource can come from either an actual file or a jar entry, but a JSSE truststore set with that property can only come from an actual file.

Comment: I am not running the jar, I just run the service(running Appstarter main class in intellij) in spring boot embedded tomcat.